# How to use print("\r"+progressMessage) in a Java parallelStream?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

I am trying to display a progress for my parallelStream by writing something like

```
int total=myList.size();
AtomicInteger counter=new AtomicInteger(0);

List<String> myResult=IntStream.range(0, total)
                    .parallel()
                    .mapToObj(i-> modify(myList.get(i)))
                    .peek(i->System.out.print("\r"+(counter.getAndIncrement()*100/total)+"%"))
                    .collect(toList());
```

My problem comes from the "\r". Given that it's parallelized, the amount of "\r" needed to really go to the beginning of the line may vary when concurrent events occur. So I can read sometimes "70% 71%"...

Comment: Why are you adding returns yourself? What's wrong with print**ln**?

Comment: println goes to the next line. I want to replace the old percentage with the new one. On the same line.

Comment: Eh? You can't do that.

Comment: @Michael why not, I mean using `\\r` to jump to beginning of current line? works perfectly well (on Linux). You sure must have a terminal that accept that, unlike the Eclipse console and probably the Windows one.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Okay, I've just looked it up. I didn't understand the exact semantics of a carriage return when used on its own. It seems like it probably will work on Windows.

Comment: @Michael just tested works on Windows DOS prompt as on Linux bash, but not with the Eclipse Console

Comment: Works with the Windows console; the Netbeans console interprets it as intended but repaints only when `\n` in printed…

Answer (score 3):

Separate the progress recording from the progress output operation:

```
int total = myList.size();
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
ScheduledExecutorService es = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

ScheduledFuture<?> f = es.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    int lastReported = -1;
    public void run() {
        int newValue = counter.get();
        if(newValue != lastReported) {
            lastReported = newValue;
            System.out.append("\r"+newValue*100/total+"%").flush();
        }
    }
}, 100, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

List<String> myResult = IntStream.range(0, total)
    .parallel()
    .mapToObj(i -> modify(myList.get(i)))
    .peek(i -> counter.incrementAndGet())
    .collect(toList());

f.cancel(true);
es.shutdown();
System.out.print("\r100%");
```

Now, the printing is done consistently by one thread. This separation solves even more issues.
Performing a print operation for every element will slow down your actual processing significantly. By using a scheduled printing job, you can control the overhead yourself, i.e. you don’t need printing faster than a human can read and you don’t need to perform an expensive printing operation if the percentage did not change since the last update.

Note that by the time, all elements have passed the `peek` action, the stream operation has not entirely completed (there’s at least one merge operation pending), but that’s the best progress estimate you can get with the current API.

Comment: Well, I hope, the program is simple enough to demonstrate that this is not an issue of the program. Thinking about it, the `System.out.print` of your original code uses synchronization internally, so it also shouldn’t exhibit that behavior, which suggests that the problem lies somewhere else. Still, in your original code the actions could overtake each other resulting in noncontinuous percentages printed and it also has the performance issues, so you still should adopt my suggestion. But the printing issue must lie somewhere else. As said, it works smoothly with the Windows console.

Comment: How can it result in noncontinuous percentages since it is "counter" that gets incremented and print and not "i"? Aamof, I do have monotonous values (I guess that's what you meant). I'll try to make a test method "modify()"  to isolate the question from the rest of my code and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Myoch: `counter` is queried and updated atomically. *After* that, you are using the `int` value to construct a string, which you *then* pass to `System.out.print`. Constructing a string takes some time and during that, another thread having updated `counter` at a later time may complete that string construction slightly quicker (as thread scheduling is unpredictable) and print its higher number. Then, the first thread completes its string construction with the lower number and prints it, overwriting the message with the higher number.